# Maven : Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0 compile time exception in POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

I am getting one weird issue and getting a compile time exception in my pom.xml when i am trying to add dependancy for tools. jar displayed as below(**Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0**)

[image: Issue]

I have set my JAVA_HOME variable as below:

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34

When i hardcode it to the actual path  of JDK1.6 i dont find any error as below.

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

but i know its not good practise. Request guidance in resolving this error.

Comment: Maven will use the JAVA_HOME env variable to dtermine the JDK to use. Check if that one is set correctly.

Comment: @Shirish, are you running maven command line or from an IDE?

Comment: @StijnGeukens : I am running it through my command prompt but have integrated it with my eclipse.

Comment: @StijnGeukens : Does that make any difference Stijin as when i run my commands through my command prompt like clean,compile,test i dont find any errors. Should i consider everything fine?. I have integrated my maven project with eclipse for the first time so i am a bit confused about this compile time error.

Comment: yes this might make a difference if in your eclipse you have defined other settings for the M2E plugin (I don't use eclipse anymore so I can't verify this now).

Comment: Why do you need tools.jar ?

Comment: @Shirish Sorry to post it here but I am not sure if it was you or someone else who decided to remove my comments which ware reply to your [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742386/edited-java-add-digits-of-4-numbers/26742697?noredirect=1#comment42084825_26742697). Anyway in case someone would remove them again before you could read them you can find its copies [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MEbO6.png) or [here](http://pastebin.com/Fs7f51Z4).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`java.home` is a System property which generally points to the jre directory and you are getting an error as you have pointed to a jar which doesn't exist.

In case you want to refer to an environment variable within your pom file, use the below syntax.

```
${env.variable_name}
```

In your case, it should be `${env.JAVA_HOME}` as seen below

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

**Update:** As lexicore has mentioned, this wont work with MAC as the MAC JDK has a different file structure.

Comment: This won't work on Mac.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I have updated the same in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw, well done. But it appears to be a duplicate after all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency/3080695#3080695

Answer (score 3):

In Maven, ${java.home} points to the JRE directory used by the JDK, not JDK itself. Please see this question:

[Java_home in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven)

So instead of

```
${java.home}/lib/tools.jar
```

which assumes the JDK directory you should have used

```
${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar
```

However, this is only a half of the solution. The problem is that under Mac, the directory structure is different. You have to user profiles in order to make your build relibaly work cross-platform.

Please see this question:

[JDK tools.jar as maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency)

And, specificaly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3080695/303810) (which IS the correct answer and not the one accepted by the OP there).

This is how Oracle handles it in [one of their POMs](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-parent/2.2.11/jaxb-parent-2.2.11.pom):

```
<!--  JDK dependencies  -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${tools.jar}</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

And then in `profiles`:

```
<profile>
  <id>default-tools.jar</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tools.jar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</tools.jar>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>default-tools.jar-mac</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tools.jar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</tools.jar>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

On Mac, the JDK has a different file structure. This is why you have to define these profiles.

See also the following posts:

- [JDK tools.jar as maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency)
- [Build error: missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694303/build-error-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-6)
- [missing artifact sun.jdk:tools:jar:1.6.0:system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065135/missing-artifact-sun-jdktoolsjar1-6-0system)
- [Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.5.0 maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031766/missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-5-0-maven)

Comment: Notice the difference here - they use `${java.home}/../lib` instead of `${java.home}/lib`, which suggests that `${java.home}` points to the `jre` directory inside the JDK rather than the JDK itself.

Comment: @IanRoberts Interesting. I wonder why it works then. And this may be also the cause of another problem I was facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393332/getting-the-pom-for-name-is-invalid-transitive-dependencies-if-any-will-no

I'll ask them.

Comment: @IanRoberts I have rechecked this. In Maven, ${java.home} points to the jre directory. So the configuration above is correct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279586/java-home-in-maven