# Got "Unable to create Maven project for com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 from repository." warning when using findbugs-maven-plugin in maven

Tags: java, maven, findbugs

Here's the `<reporting>` section of my pom.xml

```xml
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
                <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <excludeFilterFile>findbugs-exclude-filter.xml</excludeFilterFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

and when I run "mvn site", I got a warning said

```
[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 from repository.
```

Here 's the context of the warning:

```
[INFO] Generating "About" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Plugin Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Distribution Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Information" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Repository" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Mailing Lists" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Issue Tracking" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Continuous Integration" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Plugins" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project License" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 in http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-products-ga-repo has elapsed or updates are forced for project com.sun:tools:pom:1.6
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.RepositoryUtils.getMavenProjectFromRepository(RepositoryUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.getDependencyRow(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:259)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForScope(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForAllScopes(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderSectionProjectDependencies(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderBody(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReportRenderer.render(AbstractMavenReportRenderer.java:79)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.DependencyManagementReport.executeReport(DependencyManagementReport.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 in http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-products-ga-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:288)
    ... 37 more
    Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.sun:tools:pom:1.6 in http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-products-ga-repo has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
    ... 41 more
[INFO] Generating "Project Team" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Project Summary" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Dependencies" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
[INFO] Generating "Source Xref" report    --- maven-jxr-plugin:2.3
[INFO] Generating "Test Source Xref" report    --- maven-jxr-plugin:2.3
```

I'm using Java 1.8_u20 and maven 3.2.1.

Could anybody help to resolve the problem please?

Here's the full output log [here](http://pastebin.com/Ei7jVRd6)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven : Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0 compile time exception in POM.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422259/maven-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-6-0-compile-time-exception-in-pom-x)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `com.sun:tools` somewhere? This dependency should be included in system scope.

See the following question:

> [Maven : Missing artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6.0 compile time exception in POM.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422259/maven-missing-artifact-com-suntoolsjar1-6-0-compile-time-exception-in-pom-x/26422832#26422832)

Here's an example how to do it correctly (with profiles to make it also work on Mac):

```xml
<!--  JDK dependencies  -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${tools.jar}</systemPath>
</dependency>
...
<profile>
  <id>default-tools.jar</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tools.jar>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</tools.jar>
  </properties>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>default-tools.jar-mac</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <tools.jar>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</tools.jar>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Thank a lot, lexicore. But actually, I've not run com.sun:tools anywhere. I just run "mvn site" according to http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html. And also, I've read some refs you linked before, and they didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @TonnyTc Ok, I understand. My theory is that some of the plugins probably uses that `tools` artifact incorrectly. This is normally seen when this artifact is used without the `system` scope. But I'm puzzled, why it happens here. Please check `mvn -X -e` log.

Comment: [INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report    --- maven-project-info-reports-plugin:2.7
 ... same warning message in the post ...
[DEBUG] Multipage report: 0 subreports  it seems that the plugin wanna to generate a "Dependency Management report", and it cannot find the tools.jar file.

Comment: @TonnyTc Consider sharing your full log via pastebin in your question.

Comment: OK. I've just edited the post and added a link to the full log file.