# Edited Java add digits of 4 numbers

Tags: java

I want to add the digits of4  numbers of 1 or 2 digits using Java.

```
i1=2
i2=33
i3=12
i4=10
```

Result : 12 (2+3+3+1+2+1+0)

How could I do that?

Comment: Step 1: Get the digits.

Comment: Note don't use `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, etc. as variable names because you don't know how many digits there are. When you start using numbers in variable names, it means that you need a loop or a `List` (or both).

Comment: Please learn something before asking questions on it. Only then we can help

Comment: plz read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3389287/2227526

Comment: Wow, 9 minutes, 7 down-votes and only one trying to help! There are two different answers depending on what you want to see. Would you, for your example, really like 12 as result, or  12 ~ 1 + 2 =3?

Comment: What do you find difficult about this problem? Because without being more specific, you are asking us to write the whole program for you.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints you may need:

1) If you use `/` on arguments which will be integers then your result will also be integer.

Example:

```
int x = 7/2;
System.out.println(x);
```

output: `3` (not `3.5`)

So to get rid of last digit of integer all you can do is divide this number by 10 like

```
int x = 123;
x = x/10;
System.out.println(x);
```

Output: `12`

2) Java also have modulo operator which returns reminder from division, like `7/2=3` and `1` will be reminder. This operator is `%`

Example

```
int x = 7; 
x = x % 5;
System.out.println(x);
```

Output: `2` because `7/5=1 (2 remains)`

So to get last digit from integer you can simply use `% 10` like

```
int x = 123;
int lastDigit = x%10;
System.out.println(lastDigit);
```

Output: `3`

Now try to combine this knowledge. Get last digit of number, add it to sum, remove this last digit (repeat until will have no more digits).

Answer (score 1):

You want to do it like this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){
        int num=1234,sumOfDigits=0;
        while(num!=0){
            sumOfDigits+=num%10;
            num/=10;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of digits is : " + sumOfDigits);
    }
```

Things to understand % give the remainder of the number so when you do 1234%10 it gives 4. That is the last digit.
num/=10 means num=num/10; so this will 1234/10 will be 123 and not 123.4 as this is int by int division.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will calculate the sum of  digits :

```
int getDigitSum(int n) {
  return Math.floor(n/10) + n % 10;
}
```

Then use it on each value and sum the results.

Please note that I wrote this method only to work with numbers less than 100. You can easily create more generic method if needed.

Comment: No need to use `Math.floor()`. Integer division automatically truncates.

Comment: Also, what if the input has more than two digits?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, this is not a general function - just a simple method to solve the original request :)  As for the integer division - I agree; but I think that explicitly requesting floor makes code more clear. (Of course, in a tight loop I wouldn't recommend doing it).

Answer (score 0):

I gave a try to achieve your target on a paper though.:-).Please Try this

```
int addition=0;  
int num=243;    
  while(num>9){
   int rem;
   rem=num%10;
   addition=addition+rem;
   num=num/10;
   if(num<9) {
      addition+=num;
      num=addition;
      addition=0;
   }
  }
  System.out.println(num);
```